# How do I use queryset.update in a Django Admin action?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-queryset

I have a Django Admin action which updates values (including foreignkeys) in a model. The code is:

```
def staff_reset(self, request, queryset):
    updated=queryset.update(regstatus='registered', medicalform__medform_status='required', 
        staffmonitoringform__monitoring_status = 'required', staffreleaseform__release_status ='required',
        staffethics__ethics_status = 'required', staffethics__i_agree=False)
    self.message_user(request, ngettext(
        '%d staff registration was successfully reset.',
        '%d staff registrations were successfully reset.',
        updated,
        ) % updated, messages.SUCCESS)
staff_reset.short_description="Reset Staff Registrations"
```

My Order model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    REGSTATUS = (
        ('registered', 'registered'),
        ('enrolled', 'enrolled'),
        ('holding', 'holding'),
        ('withdrawn', 'withdrawn'),
        ('waiting', 'waiting'),
        )
    FORMSTATUS = (
        ('required', 'required'),
        ('submitted', 'submitted'),
        )

    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete= models.CASCADE, null = True)
    training_registered = models.ForeignKey(TrainingInstance, on_delete= models.SET_NULL, blank = True, null = True)
    registration_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)

    releaseform = models.ForeignKey(ReleaseForm, on_delete= models.SET_NULL, blank = True, null = True)
    staffreleaseform = models.ForeignKey(StaffReleaseForm, on_delete= models.SET_NULL, blank = True, null = True)
    monitoringform = models.ForeignKey(MonitoringForm, on_delete= models.SET_NULL, blank = True, null = True)
    medicalform = models.ForeignKey(MedicalForm, on_delete= models.SET_NULL, blank = True, null = True)
    staffmonitoringform = models.ForeignKey(StaffMonitoringForm, on_delete= models.SET_NULL, blank = True, null = True)
    staffethics = models.ForeignKey(StaffEthicsForm, on_delete= models.SET_NULL, blank = True, null = True)

    regstatus = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=REGSTATUS, default='registered')
    enrolment_note = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True,blank=True, default="please ensure that ALL THREE forms are submitted. Please note your place on the NWTA will not be offered until all the forms are submitted and processed.")

    staffcheck = models.ForeignKey(StaffCheck, on_delete= models.SET_NULL, blank = True, null = True)


    par_payment = models.ForeignKey(ParticipantPayment, on_delete= models.SET_NULL, blank = True, null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.customer.username
```

The MedicalForm model has a field called medform_status:

```
medform_status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=FORMSTATUS, default='required')
```

But I get an error message saying "Order has no field named 'medicalform__medform_status'". Any ideas on if I can use the queryset.update() with foreignkeys?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your models?

Comment: In this case the updates have to be done separately per model

Answer (score 1):

In this case each foreign key needs to be updated separately like this:

```
    updated = queryset.update(regstatus='registered')

    MedicalForm.objects.filter(
        pk__in=queryset.values('medicalform')
    ).update(medform_status='required')

    StaffMonitoringForm.objects.filter(
        pk__in=queryset.values('staffmonitoringform')
    ).update(monitoring_status='required')

    StaffReleaseForm.objects.filter(
        pk__in=queryset.values('staffreleaseform')
    ).update(release_status='required')

    StaffEthicsForm.objects.filter(
        pk__in=queryset.values('staffethics')
    ).update(ethics_status='required', i_agree=False)
```